# Interesting question about the Thomson problem for arbitrary number of electrons

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, convex-analysis, physics

This question is crossposted from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4718200/908975) I believe this is a pretty hard question and so I decided to repost the question in the Math Overflow forum. If there is something wrong with doing this, I am sorry in advance and this question can be deleted.

Anyway, the question goes as follows:

I am looking forward to answering the question

> Show that for $4$ or more points in the Thomson problem, a configuration of equidistant points in the equator line **DOES NOT** give a minimal configuration.

For some context and in really fast terms, the Thomson problem consists in solving the optimization problem

$$ \min_{x_1, \dots, x_N \in \mathbb R^3} \quad U(\mathbf x) = \sum_{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n} \frac{1}{\| x_i-x_j\|} \qquad \text{ subject to } \| x_i\|^2 = 1, \forall i \in \{1, \dots, n\}.$$

I was able to solve the $4$ points case by looking at [this answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4435781/908975), which seems to answer this question indirectly. In fact, it is shown that the optimal configuration **must** only be a tetraedron, which can't be represented by equally distant points in the equator line.

For more points, I started by thinking about how we can distribut equally distant points in the equator line. After talking to the professor who gave me this task, we came to the conclusion that "equally distant" isn't the most appropriate word for what we wish. To get a sense of what I am talking, for $4$ points, one possible distribution of the so called "equally distant" points is

[image]

After some thinking process about this, one comes to the conlcusion that for arbitrary $N$ points, this equally distributed points can be described by
$$ x_{k+1} = \left( \cos\left( \frac{2\pi}{N}k \right), \sin\left( \frac{2\pi}{N}k \right), 0  \right) , \quad \text{ for } k = 0,\dots,N-1.$$

Note that every other possibility is just obtained by rotating this points. But from here I don't know how to proceed. I have tried to think about lifting one of the points while keeping the other ones fixed, but it seems to me (after some calculations) that this would make the funcion value to increase instead of decreasing.

I would apreciatte any hints or help regarding this topic.

Thanks for any help in advance.

---

**UPDATE.**

After some computations, I was able to find the distance $\| x_i - x_j \|,$ for every pair $(i,j)$ (recall the vectors $x_{k+1}$ defined above). This yileds the objective function value with the equally distant points in the equator. The formula I derived for the distance is:

$$ \| x_i - x_j \| = \sqrt 2 \sqrt{1-\cos\left( \frac{2\pi}{N}(j-i) \right)}. $$

This leads the objective function (calculated in the points $x_{k+1}$) to be

$$ \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sum_{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos\left( \frac{2\pi}{N}(j-i) \right)}}.$$

I don't know how to proceed after this thought.

**FURTHER UPDATE.**

Based on the latest update, I was able to "simplify" the expression a little bit more, removing the indexes $i$ and $j$. To do this, I counted exactly how many times the difference $j-i = k$ would occur for arbitrary $k \in [1,N-1]$ (turns out it is $N-k$). By doing this, the value of the objective function (calculated in the point $x_{k+1}$) becomes just

$$ U(\mathbf x) =    \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sum_{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{N}(j-i) \right)}} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{N-k}{\sqrt{1-\cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{N}k \right)}}.$$

Again, I will keep thinking how to proceed from here.

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo This question was proposed to me as a task by a professor (there is a line in the post where I state this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only need to consider $n\ge5$.

Let us move each of the $n$ "equidistant points" on the equator slightly towards one of the two poles of the globe, so that after such a movement the points on the sphere become
\begin{equation*}
    x_k(t):=\Big(\sqrt{1-t^2 z_k^2}\,\cos\frac{ 2\pi k}{n},
    \sqrt{1-t^2 z_k^2}\,\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n},t z_k\Big),
\end{equation*}
where (say) $k=0,\dots,n-1$, the $z_k$'s are real numbers (to be chosen later), and $t\ge0$ is  small. So, at $t=0$ we get the original $n$ "equidistant points" on the equator line.

The corresponding potential energy is
\begin{equation*}
    u(t):=\sum_{0\le i<j\le n-1}\frac1{\|x_i(t)-x_j(t)\|}, 
\end{equation*}
so that $u(0)$ is the initial potential energy, of $n$ "equidistant points" on the equator. Obviously, $u'(0)=0$. So, consider
\begin{equation*}
    u''(0)=\sum_{0\le i<j\le n-1}
    \frac{2 z_i z_j-(z_i^2+z_j^2) \cos \dfrac{2 \pi(i-j)}{n}}
   {2^{3/2}\Big(1- \cos \dfrac{2 \pi(i-j)}{n}\Big)^{3/2}}. 
\end{equation*}

We want to choose the $z_k$'s so that $u''(0)<0$. It appears that the alternating choice $z_k:=(-1)^k$ for all $k$ will do.

However, it is somewhat more convenient to choose the $z_k$'s at random. Namely, let the $z_k$'s be independent Rademacher random variables, so that $P(z_k=\pm1)=1/2$ for each $k$. Then, after taking the expectation, the term $z_i z_j$ disappears:
\begin{equation*}
E   u''(0)=-\frac{s_n}{\sqrt2},
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    s_n:=\sum_{0\le i<j\le n-1}a_{j-i}=\sum_{1\le k\le n-1}(n-k)a_k, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    a_k:=a_{n,k}:=A(k/n),\quad A(x):=\frac{\cos 2 \pi x} {(1- \cos 2 \pi x)^{3/2}}. 
\end{equation*}

So, it suffices to show that $s_n>0$ for $n\ge5$.

Using the substitution $y:=\cos 2 \pi x$, we see that for all $x\in(0,1)$
\begin{equation*}
    A(x)\ge a_{\min}:=-\frac1{2\sqrt2}
\end{equation*}
Also, if an integer $k$ is such that $1\le k\le \lfloor n/8\rfloor=:k_n$, then $\cos2\pi\frac kn\ge\cos\frac\pi4=1/\sqrt2$ and hence $a_k\ge a_*:=\dfrac{1/\sqrt2} {(1- 1/\sqrt2)^{3/2}}$. So,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    s_n&\ge a_*\sum_{1\le k\le k_n}(n-k)+a_{\min}\sum_{1\le k\le n-1}(n-k) \\ 
    &=\frac{(2n-1)k_n-k_n^2}{2 \sqrt{2}
   \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{n^2-n}{4 \sqrt{2}} \\ 
    &>\frac{(2n-1)(n/8-1)-(n/8-1)^2}{2 \sqrt{2}
   \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{n^2-n}{4 \sqrt{2}} \\ 
   &>-4.006 n + 0.345 n^2 >0 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
for $n\ge12$. That $s_n>0$ for $n=5,\dots,11$ is easy to check. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Dear Iosif, I've a question about your solution. Could you justify that your parametrisation $x_1(t),\ldots, x_n(t)$ go through all possible points of $\mathbb S^2$ as $t$ varies in $[-\min_k|a_k|,\min_k|a_k|]$?

Comment: Hello Iosif. Thanks for your answer to my problem. I have to say I understood mostly everything, except a few "details" ( important details, I would say).  Basically, I guess I understand everything until the last inequality, i.e., until $$ s_n \geq a_{\star} \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n/8} (n-k) + a_{min} \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n-1} (n-k) > 0. $$ I really can't understand where this inequality comes from. Can you be a little bit more detailed in this part? Also, how does this only work for $n \geqslant 12?$ Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Fawen90 : I did not make or use such a claim, that the parametrization 
covers all possible points of the sphere (and it does not -- we are going along the meridian from each of the $n$ points on the equator towards one of the poles). Please look at the question, highlighted in the OP.

Comment: @Rodrigo : The two sums in your comments are just the sums of arithmetic progressions. I have added details about that.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks Iosif for the clarification. I get it

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks. I understood that part of the inequality originally. The one I didn't understand is how you get that $$ s_n \geqslant a_\star \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant k_n} (n-k) + a_{min} \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n-1} (n-k), $$ for every $n \geqslant 12.$ I did the following: $$ s_n = \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant k_n} (n-k)a_k + \sum_{k_n < k \leqslant n-1} (n-k)a_k.$$ From here, one gets $$ s_n \geqslant a_{\star} \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant k_n} (n-k) + a_{min} \sum_{k_n < k \leqslant n-1} (n-k) $$. I will keep writing in a comment below (out of characters).

Comment: From the last inequality, I believe it follows that $$ s_n \geqslant a_{\star} \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant k_n} (n-k) + a_{min} \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n-1} (n-k),$$ since $a_{min}$ is negative. The part I don't understand is how is this only valid for $n \geq 12$.

Comment: @Rodrigo : I think you actually understood everything in the answer that I **actually** said. :-) The condition $n\ge12$ is needed and used only for the last inequality in that multiline display -- and I did not say that other inequalities are true **only** for $n\ge12$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Got it... Thank you so much for your help. Really clarifying.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry to disturb you again. I have one final doubt: How does $s_n > 0$ imply that $u''(0) < 0?$ I understand it implies $Eu''(0) < 0$ but I don't know how to reach $u''(0) < 0$. I am not really good at probability, perhaps I am missing something really obvious.

Comment: @Rodrigo : $u''(0)$ is a random variable, whose values depend on the values of Rademacher random signs $z_0,\dots,z_{n-1}$. If the average $Eu''(0)$ of the values of $u''(0)$ (over all possible sequences of the signs) is $<0$, then there **exist some** values of the signs $z_0,\dots,z_{n-1}$ for which the value of the random variable $u''(0)$ is $<0$ -- because the average of nonnegative numbers is nonnegative, whereas our average $Eu''(0)$ is $<0$.